# How to concatenate datetime arrays without changing the type?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, datetime, matplotlib

So basically I wanted to add 4 arrays of date/times to the end of each other (i.e. [1,2,3] + [1,2,3] => [1,2,3,1,2,3]) this is what I tried where data is a dataframe:

```
 x=np.concatenate((data.index,data.index,data.index,data.index))
```

Then when I tried to plot it (y and z were fine):

```
ax = plt.axes(projection="3d")
ax.scatter3D(x, y, z, c=z, cmap='hsv');
```

I got the error that x was not a datetime type, my guess is because using numpy.concatenate changed the type, for example this input:

```
print(x[1])
print(data.index[1])
```

gives this output:

```
  2019-09-22T23:58:00.000000000
  2019-09-22 23:58:00
```

So my question is, how can I concatenate these arrays so that matplotlib is happy with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try setting the axis parameter to none (default is 0)

```
np.concatenate((a, b), axis=None)
```

Comment: Yup this works great! What exactly does an axis of 0 imply?

Comment: defines the axis along which the arrays will be joined. If axis is None, arrays are flattened before use. you can check in the documentation https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html

Answer (score 0):

Also another workaround that I found that may be useful to someone was to convert it to seconds:

```
 x=np.concatenate((data.index,data.index,data.index,data.index))                                                            
 ts = (x - np.datetime64('1970-01-01T00:00:00')) / np.timedelta64(1, 's') 
 ax = plt.axes(projection="3d")
 ax.scatter3D(ts, y, z, c=XX, cmap='hsv');
```